# Why does comparing two images take longer when running the procedure in parallel using python's Pool module?

Tags: python, image-processing, parallel-processing, pool, sentence-transformers

I'm developing a program that involves computing similarity scores for around 480 pairs of images (20 directories with around 24 images in each). I'm utilizing the `sentence_transformers` Python module for image comparison, and it takes around 0.1 - 0.2 seconds on my Windows 11 machine to compare two images when running in serial, but for some reason, that time gets increased to between 1.5 and 3.0 seconds when running in parallel using a process `Pool`. So, either a), there's something going on behind the scenes that I'm not yet aware of, or b) I just did it wrong.

Here's a rough structure of the image comparison function:

```
def compare_images(image_one, image_two, clip_model):
    start = time()
    images = [image_one, image_two]
    # clip_model is set to SentenceTransformer('clip-ViT-B-32') elsewhere in the code
    encoded_images = clip_model.encode(images, batch_size = 2, convert_to_tensor = True, show_progress_bar = False)
    processed_images = util.paraphrase_mining_embeddings(encoded_images)
    stop = time()
    print("Comparison time: %f" % (stop - start) )
    score, image_id1, image_id2 = processed_images[0]
    return score
```

Here's a rough structure of the serial version of the code to compare every image:

```
def compare_all_images(candidate_image, directory, clip_model):
    for dir_entry in os.scandir(directory):
        dir_image_path = dir_entry.path
        dir_image = Image.open(dir_image_path)
        similiarity_score = compare_images(candidate_image, dir_image, clip_model)

        # ... code to determine whether this is the maximum score the program has seen...
```

Here is a rough structure of the parallel version:

```
def compare_all_images(candidate_image, directory, clip_model):
    pool_results = dict()
    pool = Pool()

    for dir_entry in os.scandir(directory):
        dir_image_path = dir_entry.path
        dir_image = Image.open(dir_image_path)
        pool_results[dir_image_path] = pool.apply_async(compare_images, args = (candidate_image, dir_image, clip_model)

    # Added everything to the pool, close it and wait for everything to finish
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    # ... remaining code to determine which image has the highest similarity rating
```

I'm not sure where I might be erring.

The interesting thing here is that I also developed a smaller program to verify whether I was doing things correctly:

```
def func():
    sleep(6)

def main():
    pool = Pool()
    for i in range(20):
        pool.apply_async(func)
    pool.close()

    start = time()
    pool.join()
    stop = time()
    print("Time: %f" % (stop - start) ) # This gave an average of 12 seconds 
                                        # across multiple runs on my Windows 11 
                                        # machine, on which multiprocessing.cpu_count=12
```

Is this a problem with trying to make things parallel with sentence transformers, or does the problem lie elsewhere?

**UPDATE:** Now I'm especially confused. I'm now only passing `str` objects to the comparison function and have temporarily slapped a `return 0` as the very first line in the function to see if I can further isolate the issue. Oddly, even though the parallel function is doing absolutely nothing now, several seconds (usually around 5) still seem to pass between the time that the pool is closed and the time that `pool.join()` finishes. Any thoughts?

**UPDATE 2:** I've done some more playing around, and have found out that *an empty pool still has some overhead*. This is the code I'm testing out currently:

```
            # ...
            pool = Pool()

            pool.close()
            start = time()
            DebuggingUtilities.debug("empty pool closed, doing a join on the empty pool to see if directory traversal is messing things up")
            pool.join()
            stop = time()

            DebuggingUtilities.debug("Empty pool join time: %f" % (stop - start) )
```

This gives me an "Empty pool join time" of about 5 seconds. Moving this snippet to the very first part of my main function still yields the same. Perhaps `Pool` works differently on Windows? In WSL (Ubuntu 20.04), the same code runs in about 0.02 seconds. So, what would cause even an empty `Pool` to hang for such a long time on Windows?

**UPDATE 3:** I've made another discovery. The empty pool problem goes away if the only imports I have are `from multiprocessing import Pool` and `from time import time`. However, the program uses a boatload of import statements across several source files, which causes the program to hang a bit when it first starts. I suspect that this is propagating down into the `Pool` for some reason. Unfortunately, I need all of the `import` statements that are in the source files, so I'm not sure how to get around this (or why the imports would affect an empty Pool).

**UPDATE 4:** So, apparently it's the `from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer` line that's causing issues (without that import, the `pool.join()` call happens relatively quickly. I think the easiest solution now is to simply move the `compare_images` function into a separate file. I'll update this question again with updates as I implement this.

**UPDATE 5:** I've done a little more playing around, and it seems like on Windows, the import statements get executed multiple times whenever a `Pool` gets created, which I think is just weird. Here's the code I used to verify this:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from datetime import datetime
from time import time
from utils import test

print("outside function lol")

def get_time():

    now = datetime.now()

    return "%02d/%02d/%04d - %02d:%02d:%02d" % (now.month, now.day, now.year, now.hour, now.minute, now.second)


def main():
    pool = Pool()

    print("Starting pool")

    """
    for i in range(4):
        print("applying %d to pool %s" % (i, get_time() ) )
        pool.apply_async(test, args = (i, ) )
    """

    pool.close()
    print("Pool closed, waiting for all processes to finish")
    start = time()
    pool.join()

    stop = time()

    print("pool done: %f" % (stop - start) )

if __name__ == "__main__":

    main()
```

Running through Windows command prompt:

```
outside function lol
Starting pool
Pool closed, waiting for all processes to finish
outside function lol
outside function lol
outside function lol
outside function lol
outside function lol
outside function lol
outside function lol
outside function lol
outside function lol
outside function lol
outside function lol
outside function lol
pool done: 4.794051
```

Running through WSL:

```
outside function lol
Starting pool
Pool closed, waiting for all processes to finish
pool done: 0.048856
```

**UPDATE 6:** I think I might have a workaround, which is to create the `Pool` in a file that doesn't directly or indirectly import anything from `sentence_transformers`. I then pass the model and anything else I need from `sentence_transformers` as parameters to a function that handles the `Pool` and kicks off all of the parallel processes. Since the `sentence_transformers` import seems to be the only problematic one, I'll wrap that import statement in an `if __name__ == "__main__"` so it only runs once, which will be fine, as I'm passing the things I need from it as parameters. It's a rather janky solution, and probably not what others would consider as "Pythonic", but I have a feeling this will work.

**UPDATE 7:** The workaround was successful. I've managed to get the pool join time on an empty pool down to something reasonable (0.2 - 0.4 seconds). The downside of this approach is that there is definitely considerable overhead in passing the entire model as a parameter to the parallel function, which I needed to do as a result of creating the `Pool` in a different place than the model was being imported. I'm quite close, though.

Comment: A common reason for this is due to the overhead of passing large amounts of data between the processes (like image data). You might be able to work around it by only passing file names.

Comment: I'm not sure what point you were trying to make about the results with the smaller program at the end, but getting 20 processes that each take 6 seconds to run to finish in 12 seconds is what I would consider pretty good performance.

Comment: You need to read the image inside the parallel job, not in the serial section. A Python pool implies separate Python processes running, with the master process passing data to the other processes. It is highly inefficient to do lots of work in the master program and then pass lots of data across process bounds, as opposed to having each parallel process do all the work for one file.

Comment: @martineau That's something I hadn't considered. When I get a chance, I will definitely rework the logic to open the images in the parallel function. The point I was trying to convey with the smaller program was that I used the same mechanics for setting up a `Pool` and running function there as I did in the larger program, and I wanted to see if that was the underlying issue.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks for that; I'll rework my code at some point to reflect this. Would you also recommend loading the CLIP model inside of the parallel job as well, or would this actually increase computation time? [This](https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers/blob/master/sentence_transformers/SentenceTransformer.py) makes it seem like a `SentenceTransformer` object is fairly large, but I'm not sure if passing the entire model across processes is expensive or not.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand that need to minimize the passing of *all* data between the processes.

Comment: If in doubt, time it. Try both options and see which one is more efficient.

Comment: Loading the model in the parallel function is far less performant for me, actually increasing execution time. I will try surrounding the model loading statement in a `with self.lock` (or something to that effect); perhaps there's some issue because the model is being loaded from the same files multiple times...

Comment: Scratch the above; that will just cause the entire program to run longer.

Comment: What `Pool` are you using? From `multiprocessing`? (PS always show complete code, including import statements!). There are [alternatives](https://towardsdatascience.com/mpire-for-python-multiprocessing-is-really-easy-d2ae7999a3e9). But in general with `multiprocessing` and similar packages you want to use `map()` rather than `apply_async`. On Linux or macOS use the `forkserver` start method.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Yes, it's from `multiprocessing`. I'll look into `map()` as well; thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done a little more digging, and think I've finally discovered the root of the problem, and it has everything to do with what's described [here](https://www.pythonforthelab.com/blog/differences-between-multiprocessing-windows-and-linux/).

To summarize, on Linux systems, processes are forked from the main process, meaning that the current process state is copied (which is why the `import` statements don't run multiple times). On Windows (and macOS), processes are spawned, meaning that interpreter starts at the beginning of the "main" file, thus running all `import` statements again. So, the behavior I'm seeing is not a bug, but I will need to rethink my program design to account for this.